# Revit "Parts" not selectable in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In Revit we have divided some objects in a model into parts. Uploading the .rvt file to Forge, those parts are not selectable in the viewer.
Is there a possibility make each part behave like a separate object in the Forge Viewer?

[Screenshot from Forge viewer in our application + Revit screenshot: in Revit the single parts can be selected, in the Forge Viewer it is one object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhTan.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you create the part for the wall. If you do create the wall part in the 3D view, please make sure you have picked the 3D view inside the view set of the Publish Settings of Revit before uploading to Forge. Check here for instruction of the Publish Settings:

- https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/publishing-settings-revit-for-bim-360.html
- https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-Cloud/files/GUID-A2444193-FCE8-4219-A590-62CA2B8B5C5D-htm.html

Here are the snapshots of my test result:
[image]
[image]